# Загрузка файлов и медиа запросы

Tags: css

Всем известно, что стили из медиа запросов не применяются, если устройство не подходит под параметры, указанные в запросе. А что с файлами, например, background: url("...") no-repeat; Т.е., css файл, внутри которого несколько медиа запросов: десктоп, планшет, телефон и 3 url с бэкграундами на каждое устройство. Они ведь не будут загружаться все, а загрузится только соответствующий медиа запросу, так? Например сайт открыт с телефона – загрузился один бэкграунд из соответствующего медиа запроса.

Comment: интересный вопрос. я бы на твоем месте просто провел тест - открыл бы консоль в браузере на вкладке network и перезагрузил бы страницу - там ты сразу увидишь какие были картинки подгружены и сразу станет понятно как оно работает)

Comment: Уже полез в неё, буду тестировать.

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос показался интересным, решил поиграться. Сделал простецкий index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            @media screen and (max-width: 1920px) {
                body {
                    background: url("./some/path/doesnt/matter1920.jpg");
                }
            }
            @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
                body {
                    background: url("./some/path/doesnt/matter600.jpg");
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Вот что получилось в хроме:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Видна попытка загрузки только одной картинки. Если подергать ширину окна, то появляется вторая:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Если грузить сразу маленьким окном(по-идее условие `max-width:1920px` тоже проходит), то все равно видим только маленькую картинку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А вот IE 11 сразу обе попытался грузануть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
"Узкий" IE 11 только маленькую картинку захотел грузить:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можете поиграться сами с другими браузерами. Мне лень их устанавливать.

Или другими параметрами медиа запроса.

---

**UPD**
Теперь такой эксперимент. Допустим мы теперь эти картинки разнесем по разным `CSS`. Делаем такой `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-width: 1920px)' href='./css1920.css' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-width: 600px)' href='./css600.css' />
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Рядом положим две css, по которым разнесем картинки. css600.css:

```
body {
    background: url("./some/path/doesnt/matter600.jpg");
}
```

И css1920.css:

```
body {
    background: url("./some/path/doesnt/matter1920.jpg");
}
```

Теперь хром грузит обе `CSS`, но картинку только одну:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

IE по-прежнему грузит всё для полного окна:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И только маленькую картинку для маленького окна:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Интересно, т.е. даже из различных подходящих медиа запросов браузер выбирает только одну картинку, а не загружает их поочерёдно.

Comment: Видно, что поведение немного разное в разных браузерах. Сейчас еще одну мысль проверяю

Comment: любопытный опыт, возьму на заметку, спасибо!) (самому было лень тестировать Т_Т)

Comment: В качестве подстраховки можно использовать @media(min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 1920px), вместо @media screen and (max-width: 1920px), тогда маленький экран не попадёт под под первый медиа запрос, даже если какой-то из браузеров будет загружать картинки всех подходящих медиа запросов.

Comment: @DenisRoss Простое любопытство взяло) Хотя я даже не фронтендер. Так, приходится иногда

Comment: @halfPeiceOfGangsta Этот вариант тоже следует проверить. Браузеры все равно увидят оба бэкграунда. Как они будут обрабатывать - предлагаю Вам уже самостоятельно проверить. Мне пора закругляться